# java fill 2 dimensional array with random 0's and 1's

Tags: java, arrays, math

I was wondering if you can use the Math.random method to generate random 0's and 1's?

I need to fill up a 2 dimensional array to make it essentially like a maze with the 1's being the path and 0's being the walls.

Comment: Mazes are not random. They must be structured where there is an entry, an exit, and a path between the two. Randomness will not get you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maze with random paths is no more a valid maze! The paths in a maze are fixed and not random, though they seem to be! say for example,

[image]

The above one is a valid maze, but once the paths are random,its no longer a valid maze!(below)

[image]

Here are some examples of [maze generation codes](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, I don't think you want random if you're trying to generate mazes. Instead, take a look at some of the algorithms here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use the following to generate random 0s and 1s:

```
Random r = new Random( );
int[][] maze = ...
...
maze[x][y] = r.nextInt(2);
// or, equivalently, maze[x][y] = r.nextBoolean( ) ? 1 : 0;
```

This isn't likely to produce a very nice maze however. As Jonathan says, mazes have structure (i.e. are **not** completely random), and you'll need a decent maze construction algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
int n = 10;
int[][] maze = new int[n][n];
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        maze[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);
```

Although I agree with the comments, that won't give you nice mazes...